# Adding diacritics slowly

Tags: key-bindings

One can make `e/` produce `é` with `inoremap e/ é`; but this only works if `/` is typed before `timeoutlen` seconds have passed.  Is there a way to make `/` after `e` produce the same result, regardless of the time elapsed?  The bare `e` should be visible after timeout, but changed if a `/` is entered.

Comment: Disable timeouts, while showing already typed letters to Vim's bottom-right: `set showcmd notimeout nottimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
function! s:accent_e()
  if getline('.') =~# 'e/$'
    call feedkeys("\<bs>\<bs>é")
  endif
endfunction

autocmd! TextChangedI * call s:accent_e()
```

However, that doesn't seem like a good solution.  You'll end up needing a way to disable it if you want to type path components that end with an `e` since `i_CTRL-V` wouldn't help with the method above.  Have you looked at `:help digraph` and `:help i_CTRL-K`?  In insert mode you can type <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> to get `é`.

A few other examples:

<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> = `è`

<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> = `ë`

etc.

Using <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, not only will you be deliberate with the character entry, you'll have all the time you need.